# Using Eloquent Model class. Where is the implementation of static method "where"?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

Consider this code

```
$match_get1 = Model::where(SyncVariableConstant::MAIN_ID_FIELD_NAME, $sqlId)->get();
```

I really don't understand where is the definition of the **where** static method in the **Model::** class context. Model class doesn't not implement the method **where** ([source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php)).

Obviously, I think this is a kind of php mecanism i am not familar with...

Does sommeone have an explaination?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Models generally extend `Eloquent` facade, which is just a shortcut to underlying `app('db')` instance.

The `where()` method you are looking for resides in `\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` namespace. This namespace is used by Eloquent ORM, the code of which lies within `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` namespace. Both classes have `where()` methods. If you check the latter class, you will see that in it's constructor it injects the former class as a dependency (i.e. Dependency Injection).

In a nutshell, `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` is high-level user of `\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`, both of which have `where()` implemented.

And how high-level `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` is invoked? As another user here already stated, through magic-getter `__call()`

Comment: Eloquent isn't a facade.

Answer (score 1):

The 'magic' actually happens inside the magic method `__callStatic` and `__call()` in `Model.php`.

If a method is not found in the class, most likely it's being handled by these magic methods.

If you put a `dd($method);` inside `__call()`, you would get `where`.

From [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call):

> __call() is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in an object context.